# http status code 200 returns expected result. But when status is BadRequest or Unauthorized, my C# webapi 1 is returning text/html

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        sessionResponse.message = "Not permitted";
        sessionResponse.code = statusCode.Unauthorized;

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, sessionResponse);
        return response;
    }
```

This is giving me total html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title></head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
<h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
<h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I am running this code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        sessionResponse.message = "Not permitted";
        sessionResponse.code = statusCode.Unauthorized;

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, sessionResponse);
        return response;
    }
```

I am getting desired JSON:
    {
    message: "Not permitted",
    code:"401"
    }

So, I am facing the problem when response is not HTTPSTATUSCODE.OK, I am not getting JSON. If status code is Bad request or Unauthorized, I am getting text/html. What to do with it ? I have added JSON formatter in apiconfig file, but no luck.

Comment: What is `sessionResponse`? It looks really strange with camel case properties.

Comment: "sessionResponse" is a model. it has two properties, string message and string code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Request.CreateResponse` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969057(v=vs.118).aspx)  which accepts a `MediaTypeFormatter` type or the media type via a `string` to explicitly state the formatter you wish to use:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, sessionResponse, "application/json");
```

Comment: You are returning HTTP 200. @dmsbilas wanted to have 401.

Comment: I tried with these approaches earlier but didn't work .